# From a `FutureBuilder`, my future never returns data

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

In a future builder, I use the following future that should return the number of documents (The collection stores "seen" event of an ad detailed view):

```dart
 /// Stores and returns the document [id].
  static Future<int> getCount({required String? adId}) {
    if (adId == null) return Future<int>.value(0);

    // = Actually store the document
    final c = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .where("adId", isEqualTo: adId)
        .snapshots()
        .length;

    return c;
  }
```

The `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: ClassifiedAdSeen.getCount(adId: ad.id),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Icon(Icons.error);
                        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                        final count = snapshot.data ?? "—";
                        return Text("$count");
                      }),
```

But it never `hasData` nor `hasError`, the spinner keeps on progressing.

Any idea Where the issue is, please?

[UPDATE]

By fetching the documents, I get the completion and the count with no problem.
But fetching the documents is a waste of memory and bandwidth, isn't it?

So what would be the best way of fetching only the document count?

```dart
/// Stores and returns the document [id].
  static Future<int> getCount({required String? adId}) async {
    if (adId == null) return 0;

    // = Actually store the document
    final c = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .where("adId", isEqualTo: adId)
        .get(); 

    return c.size;
  }
```

Comment: can you explain more about your Update in the post? I didn't get that.

Comment: Sure : rather to take the snapshots, I actually fetch the document with the `get()`instead of `snapshots()`. As a result, the future completes and I am able to get the document count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, which is getting only the length of documents from your query, there is also a `count()` method that returns an `AggregateQuery`, which you don't get billed for, it returns only the length of the documents, nothing else.

Give it a try:

```
/// Stores and returns the document [id].
  static Future<int> getCount({required String? adId}) async {
    if (adId == null) return 0;

    // = Actually store the document
    final c = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .where("adId", isEqualTo: adId)
        .count()
        .get(); 

    return c.count;
  }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried to make use of count() without success. I see in the answer that I had to get() the count. Let me try this right now.

Comment: Yep, thanks  exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshots()` returns a `Stream`, since you said that you want just to get the number of the documents on your query, consider using `get()`, in addition that you need an `async/await` in your method, then return the `QuerySnapshot` in your `Future` method, then call the length on it's `docs` property :

```
  static Future<QuerySnapshot> getQuerySnapshot({required String? adId})  async {
    
    final c = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .where("adId", isEqualTo: adId)
        .get();    
    return c;
  }
```

`FutureBuilder` :

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              future: ClassifiedAdSeen.getQuerySnapshot(adId: ad.id),
              builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Icon(Icons.error);
                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                final count = snapshot.data.docs.length ?? "—"; // like this
                return Text("$count");
              }),
```

Comment: Yep, that was what I did in my update. But doing that, all the documents are actually read off the database, right? Isn't there any better solution which consist of the database counting the docs and simply send it to me?

Comment: No, not all documents, only those you query in `c`

Comment: wait I have another answer